# using a function defined in a kendo model later in that model

Tags: kendo-ui

OK, I'm obviously not understanding how functions are used in javascript.  Given the below code snippet, mozilla firefox is telling me that calcUpper is not defined.  Basically I want to define a function and use that function later on in the view on different fields.  I tried moving the function definition outside of the kendo model, but with no better results.  Can someone show me how I can achieve this?

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  calcUpper: function (fieldName) {
    var value = this.get(fieldName);

    if (value == "")
      return "";
    else
      return parseInt(value) - 1;
  },
  jobNum: '',
  SRCPerif: '',
  SRCOnTargetUpper: calcUpper('SRCPerif'),
  SRCOnTargetLower: '',
  SRCConcernUpper: calcUpper('SRCOnTargetLower'),
  //...other fields...
});
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the function from the `viewModel` object?

Comment: I thikn that's the issue I am trying to set that function to equal another field.  Look at the SRCOnTargetUpper field further down in my view model.  I want that field to be a dependent field that is equal to that function when it is passed the field name which is another field on my viewmodel.  Basically I just want the ssame function to be able to be executed multiple times with different fields without having to rewrite it for every field in the viewmodel.